# firewalld stop outgoing traffic to a particular ip address

Tags: centos, redhat, firewalld

I have centos 7. I'm trying to stop all outbound traffic from a server to a specific ip address, but firewalld is not blocking the traffic. Here's what I did:

```
[root@server network-scripts]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="134.223.116.100" drop

[root@server network-scripts]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
  interfaces: ens192

[root@server network-scripts]# firewall-cmd --state
running
```

But I can still curl to the ip address, so what is wrong?

```
[root@server network-scripts]# curl 134.223.116.100
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't like debugging firewall issues from a front-end and prefer to look at the actual rule sets with `[sudo] iptables -L -v -n` or `[sudo] iptables-save`.
I *think* that will show that your rich rule is still only applied to incoming connections, rather than outgoing.

To use firewalld for anything but incoming traffic is AFAIK  rather difficult to achieve and you may have to resort to [***direct***](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.direct.html) rules

```
 sudo firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 134.223.116.100/32  -j REJECT
```

Comment: Any solution for doing this with a really long ip cidr list?

Comment: @SteveMoretz yes - load the list of IP-ranges into kernel memory with [`ipset hash:net`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ipset) and add a single netfilter/iptables rule referencing that set rather than duplicating that rule for each IP-range. For example https://serverfault.com/a/675605/37681